# Проблема с Callback api в вк

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, callback

Делаю бота для группы, запросы идут, а сообщение нет и как вывести $data, чтобы я мог на нее посмотреть?

```
<?php

$token = 'токен';

$confirmation_token = 'конфтокен';


if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
    return;
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

switch ($data->type) {
    case 'confirmation':
        echo $confirmation_token;
        break;

    case 'message_new':
        $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
       // $message = $data->object->text;
        $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&v=5.0"));
        $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;
        $request_params = array(
            'message' => "Hello, {$user_name}!",
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.107'
        );

        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);


        echo('ok');

        break;
}
```

Comment: может проблема в кодировке? Хотя стоит utf8

Answer (score 0):

Для метода `messages.send` надо обязательно указывать аргумент `random_id=0` без него сообщение не отправится.

Вывести значение `$data` можно например в файл

```
file_put_contents("callback.log", date("[d-m-Y H:i:s] ").json_encode($data)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

В этом примере создастся `callback.log` в папке со скриптом

Кроме того ваш код надо дополнить логированием ошибок в случае если вызов API завершился неудачно, например так:

```
$request_params = array(
    'message' => "Hello, {$user_name}!",
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'access_token' => $token,
    'random_id' => '0',
    'v' => '5.107'
);

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$res = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params, false, $context);
$responseData = json_decode($res);
if (!$responseData || isset($responseData['error'])) {
    file_put_contents("callback.log", date('[d-m-Y H:i:s] ') . "messages.send: response: " . $res . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```